# 2 java processes - one reading and one writing to the same file

Tags: java, file

I have two java processes which I want completely decoupled from each other.

I figure that the best way to do this is for one to write out its data to file and the other to read it from that file (the second might also have to write to the file to say its processed the line).

Problems I envisage are do with similtaneous access to the file.  Is there a good simple pattern I can use to get around this problem?  Is there a library that handles this sort of functionality?

Best way to describe it is as a simple direct message passing mechanism I could implement using files. (Simpler than JMS).

Thanks Dan

Comment: Why not just use sockets and ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream ?

Comment: Because I want them completely decoupled - so they might not be running at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple solution and you can assume that "rename file" is an atomic operation (this is not completely true), each one of the processes can rename the file when reading it or writing to it and rename back when it finishes. The other one will not find the file and will wait until the file appears.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like a named pipe? it's possible but java doesn't allow pipe creation unless you use non portable processes

Comment: No - more like using a simple form of JMS that I could implement using files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not locked on a file-based solution, a database can solve your problem.
Each record will be a line written by the writing process. A single column in the record will be untouched and the reading process will use it to indicate that it red the record.

Naturally you will have to deal with cleanup of the table before it becomes to large, or its partitioning so it will be easy for the reading process to find information inside it.

If you must use a file - you can think of another file that just has the `ID` of the record that the reader process read - that way you don't need to have concurrently writing processes on the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for functionality that is exactly what JMS does. JMS is an API which has many implemententations. Can you you not just use a lightweight implementation? I don't see why you think this is "complicated". By the time you've mananged to reliably implement your solution you'll have found that it's not trivial to deal with all the edge cases.

Comment: I had to architect several solutions like that and always struggled over the choice between (S)FTPing files and using a message queue. On one side if I build stuff by hand, I'm on the hook for supporting it. On the other hand, message queue seems like an overkill for such simple task. Another consideration is the data volumes. For example we noticed that performance of FuseMQ drops significantly after the queue size hits 1M messages, relatively indifferent to the size of these messages.

Comment: Most things degrade somewhere (or fill up completely) as volume increases, whatever you write will doubtless have a bottlneck somewhere. A message queue is not overkill if the behaviour you want is pretty much exactly that of a message queue ... you seem to be exactly describing message queue requirements :-)

Comment: Maybe you right. I want as far as trying to tease their persistence framework Kaha out. But dependencies there seem to go wrong way: Kaha knows it persists MQ messages, not just chunks of bytes.

Comment: Of course you're right that a lightweight implementation of JMS is not comlplicated.  But try working for a bank or other such organisation and upgrading a production system and then you will understand that 'complicated' is not a matter of complexity but a function of difficulty involved with deployement of new software.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I don't understand your problem...

Why don't you look at file locks ? When a program acquire the lock, the other wait until the lock is released

Comment: How can you share a lock between 2 JVMs.  If you mean a file lock - that get's too complicated.